# Select where time was 10 seconds ago

Tags: sql, forms, select, time, spam-prevention

To prevent multiple form submissions to the table **example**, I want to select the last piece of data from the table **example** where it was 10 seconds ago. If the returned result is equal to 1, then they can't submit the form. If the returned result is 0 then they can submit the form.

Is this possible, if not could you suggest another method around blocking multiple form submissions. I don't want to use the cookie method, as a user could easily block cookies.

table example

```
|-----------------------------|
|user_id | content | date_time|
|-----------------------------|
|1       | content | something|
|-----------------------------|
|2       | test    | something|
 -----------------------------|
|3       | test    | something|
 ------------------------------
```

Thanks :)

Comment: just check if there are any entries in the last 10 seconds, assuming you are storing the `DateTime` of that submission

Comment: what would the SQL query look like?

Comment: perhaps if you give us more details of your table structure, more detail help would be provided

Comment: it is currently stored as time stamp but I could change it

Comment: It depends on your reasons to block the form, but if there's no particular incentive to submit the form repeatedly, you could very well rely on cookies: people really don't block them anymore. That said, you can store the time of the transaction in the table, and do your select.

Comment: ------------------------
id | content | post_date
------------------------
1  | Test    | something
------------------------
2  | Test    | something
------------------------
3  | Test    | something

Comment: that didn't come out too well atl all

Comment: just edit your original question

Comment: @zneak If they kept submitting it they'll soon eat up all my data. And yes, I suppose cookies are my only option right now :)

Comment: @KrisIvanov I did, and as you can see, it didn't come out well..

Answer (score 1):

it is not clear if you want to limit by user or limit globally

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM [example] WHERE date_time > DATEADD (SS , -10 , GETDATE())
    )
        THEN cast(1 as bit)
        ELSE cast(0 as bit)
    END
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable];
```

this query will return you single row result set with bit value of `1` or `0` if there was an entry in the last 10 seconds, adjust as needed to fit your purpose